# make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'sim'. Stop

Tags: makefile

Below is my Makefile:

```
SIM ?= icarus
TOPLEVEL_LANG ?= verilog
VERILOG_SOURCES += $(PWD)/../hdl/dut.v
VERILOG_SOURCES += $(PWD)/wrappers/ifc_test.v

intr:
        rm -rf sim_build
        $(MAKE) sim MODULE=ifc_test TOPLEVEL=ifc_test
        include $(shell cocotb-config --makefiles)/Makefile.sim
```

But while trying to run, I'm getting the error as:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'sim'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Why do you run `$(MAKE) sim` if there's no `sim` target in the Makefile?

Comment: You should remove the indentation before the `include` line.  The recipe (the indented part) is passed to the POSIX shell to run.  The `include` line is not a POSIX shell command, it's a `make` command.  So it should not be indented.

Comment: This has nothing to do with verilog as well as unbutu and other tags. Just make. please remove extra tags.

Comment: The only make target this file describes is `intr`. Why do you think this code _should_ be able to make a `sim` target? It's like showing us a Python module that defines a function named `foo()` and asking why you get an error when you try to import `bar` from that file; the error is completely expected, because the file doesn't _try_ to define the code you're then trying to run.

Comment: If `sim` is defined by the include, then the note MadScientist added earlier about needing to remove the indentation before that `include` line is on-point. But since information about what the file being `include`d does isn't on-the-record / included in the question, we can't depend on that in writing an answer. (If you [edit] the question to specify that the include is what adds a `sim` target, then that makes the answer easy).

Comment: As mentioned, I'm assuming that the `sim` target is defined by including the file `.../Makefile.sim`.

Comment: @MadScientist, and you're almost certainly right, but if it's not on the record -- and something is put on the record when the OP edits it into the question -- answers shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: cocotb's set of Makefiles indeed has a `sim` target defined, at https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb/blob/stable/1.7/cocotb/share/makefiles/Makefile.inc#L38, which is included indirectly by the `Makefile.sim` (https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb/blob/stable/1.7/cocotb/share/makefiles/Makefile.sim) through another `Makefile.<simulatorname>` in  https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb/blob/stable/1.7/cocotb/share/makefiles/simulators/.